# Background Attachment Fixed—Google Chrome

Tags: css, fixed, background-attachment

Currently on Firefox and Safari the **background-attachment: fixed** property is working, but is not responding on Chrome.

Here is the page that works in FF & Safari
http://prestonmcpeak.com/work/enigma.html

This is the desired effect I'm looking for that is working in all three browsers:
http://codyhouse.co/demo/alternate-fixed-scroll-background/index.html

I have a feeling this has to do with a position tag somewhere on the page.

```
      <section class="project-header ">
        <div class="project-background show-for-large-up"></div>
        <section class="enigma"></section>
      </section>

        .project-header {
            section {
               position: fixed;
               height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
               top: 0;
               left: 0;
               z-index: -1;
               &.enigma {
                  background-size: contain;
                  background-attachment: fixed;
               }
            }
        .project-background {
            padding: 20% 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .enigma {
            background: url(../assets/img/enigma-1-m.jpg) no-repeat center top;
        }
```

Comment: I have the feeling you should give us what your current code is and what you did try...
For now I can just tell you you should try setting the `position` propery of the element as `static`.

Comment: What is your question? Explain difference between working and non working

Comment: @vitdes on firefox the background remains fixed as it scrolls, on chrome the image moves with the page.

Comment: @Mr.Web i've added some code if this helps give you any context, I'm coding in SCSS too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I know what the problem is. Someone on the [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/fixed-positioning-not-working-in-chrome/) forum had the same issue.

The problem is using -webkit-transform on one of the parent elements from the div you're applying the fixed background on.

To solve the problem you will have to remove the -webkit-transform from the section with the class name of "main-section".

So this:

```
.main-section {
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-45px,0);
  margin-bottom: -45px;
}
```

Should look like this:

```
.main-section {
  margin-bottom: -45px;
}
```

I managed to replicate and fix the problem on the Enigma url you provided.
Please let me know if this fixes the problem for you.

Comment: Splendid! You found the missing link. I'm loading foundation and that was a default style from their CSS, thanks for catching that!

Comment: Annoyingly this still appears to be the case. In my case, I actually had to remove all `transform: translate3d(...)` styles, even the ones that weren't parent elements of the one with the fixed background image.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way through Javascript. Since this is an issue specifically in browsers that use the [**Webkit** layout engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) (Chrome, Safari, Yandex, etc.), you can create a condition to change the `background-attachment` property in these browsers:

```
if($.browser.webkit)
  $(".project-header section.enigma").css('background-attachment', 'scroll');
```

This is for jQuery, but if you prefer pure Javascript the condition would be:

```
if(~navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("webkit"))
```

This solved the problem for my ([slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)) slider, that uses `transform: translate3d(...)` in the parent element of all the slides. Since I also wanted it to change backgrounds with the `background-size: cover` property in each slide, this was the most effective solution.